# Unable to forward remote(ec2) port to the local port using ruby "net/ssh" gem in window environment

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, net-ssh

I am trying to forward the remote(ec2) port to local port to watch the jobtracker in my local browser which is running on amazon ec2 cluster. But unable to forward the remote port.

Here is my code:

```
Net::SSH.start('ec2-23-23-4-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com' ,'hadoop' ,:keys =>"mykeypair.pem",:forward_agent => true) do |ssh|  
    ssh.forward.remote(9033, "localhost",9101,"ec2-23-22-4-249.compute-1.amazonaws.com")  
    ssh.loop { !ssh.forward.active_remotes.include?([9033, "localhost"]) }  
end
```

Comment: This doesn't answer directly your question, but might help. What I've done to view the jobtrackers webpage was connecting to it via ssh with -D option (socks proxy): ssh -i ec2key root@ec2instance -D20000. Then I configured socks proxy in my browser (localhost:20000) and could connect to the NameNode/JobTracker web pages via their private IPs.

Comment: Found the solution. It might help someone:
ssh=Net::SSH.start(dns, 'hadoop' ,:keys => ["src/#{$parameters_hash['pem_file_name']}"],:forward_agent => true)
ssh.forward.local(port_available, 'localhost', 9100)

Answer (score 0):

According to the original poster:

> Found the solution. It might help someone:
>
> ```
> ssh=Net::SSH.start(dns, 'hadoop' ,:keys => ["src/#{$parameters_hash['pem_file_name']}"],:forward_agent => true) 
> ssh.forward.local(port_available, 'localhost', 9100)
> ```